# Why is for cotangent bundles $T^*X_1 \times T^*X_2 \simeq T^*(X_1 \times X_2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

For smooth manifolds $X_1, X_2$ why can the cotangent bundle $T^*(X_1 \times X_2)$ be identified with $T^*(X_1) \times T^*(X_2)$, i.e. the product of the cotangent bundles.

I feel like this should be easy but somehow im stuck there.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Do you know the same for tangent bundles?

Comment: And then do you know that for vector spaces $V,W$, we have $(V\times W)^* \cong V^*\times W^*$? If not, you should start by proving that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand that the identity holds for tangent bundles. I am now trying to show Ted's hint. For given $\alpha \in V^*$, $\beta \in W^*$ we can define $\gamma \in (V \times W)^*$ by $\gamma = (\alpha, \beta)$. This is obviously a linear injective mapping. And since both spaces have the same dimension it should define an isomorphism. Is that correct ?

Comment: So I get an Isomorphism $T^*_{x_1} X_1 \times T^*_{x_2} X_2 \simeq (T_{x_1} \times T_{x_2})^* \simeq (T_{(x_1,x_2)}X_1 \times X_2)^*$ on each fiber.  But how can I define a homeomorphism that restricts to this isomorphism on each fiber ?

Comment: As always with vector bundles, work on open sets over which the bundle(s) trivialize.

Comment: @PaulJoh How do you mean $(\alpha,\beta)$? It should be the map $(v,w)\mapsto\alpha(v)+\beta(w)$.

Comment: Thank you @Berci, you are absolutely right. It should be $\alpha(v) + \beta(w)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Ted. I have thought about it. So I take open sets $U_1 \subset X_1, U_2 \subset X_2$ as sets over which $T^*X_1, T^*X_2 $ trivialize respectively. I then get a homeo $\phi: \pi_1^{-1}(U_1) \times \pi_2^{-1}(U_2) \to (U_1 \times \mathbb{R}^n) \times (U_2 \times \mathbb{R}^m)$. In the same way I find a homeo $\tilde{\phi}:(\pi_1 \times \pi_2)^{-1}(U) \to U \times \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. By shrinking $U_1, U_2$ if necessary I get the homeo $\tilde{\phi}^{-1} \circ \phi$. Is that correct so far ?